# Spanish for ceiling fan

Tags: vocabulario

Wordreference gives **abano** as the Spanish for a ceiling fan and **ventilador** for table fan. However, when I looked up **abano** in Google Image search (my favorite visual way of finding out the meanings of popular foreign words), no ceiling fans were returned. This has gotten me confused. I want to know from native speakers if **abano** is a word they'd use in common speech or if it's just a bookish term.

I would like to know what word would you use for a ceiling fan in your country (please specify your country too) if not **abano**. Incidentally, wordreference also gives **abanico** for a hand-held fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spain, *abano* is not any kind of ceiling fan but one very specific that I have never seen in real life, only in movies of past times: it is an apparatus with the shape of a peacock tail (abanico). In fact, I had never seen that word before now.

In English both kind of apparatus are referred to with the same word, *fan*, but in Spanish we use different words for abanicos (with peacock's tail shape that moves back and forwards) and ventiladores (apparatus with blades that spin).

In Spain we call the regular ceiling fans just *ventiladores de techo*. Based on results from Google, I think in América *abano* is used for (spinning) *ventiladores de techo* but I don't know how common is that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And what would you call a table fan in your country?

Comment: @Amit Schandillia, _ventilador de mesa_ (check images in Google :)

Comment: En Colombia le dicen abanico a los ventiladores

Comment: In México I've never seen an **abano** but all the ceiling fans are just **ventiladores de techo**.

Answer (score 0):

In Puerto Rico the word for ceiling fan is "**Albanico**". In other countries it is called "**Ventilador de techo**".